# why it is not updating url in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page named `ques.php`. If the user's answer is correct he will be directed to next `ques1.php`. The answer posted by the user is checked by check.php and if it is correct I want to store the new URL (`ques1.php`) in the users account in the database.

---

check.php

```
<?php

  require_once("./include/membersite_config.php");

  if (!$fgmembersite->CheckLogin()) {
    $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("login.php");
    exit;
  }

  mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 
  mysql_select_db("simplelogin") or die(mysql_error()); 

  $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM member") or die(mysql_error()); 

  while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) {
    // print $info['username'];
    if ($info['username'] == $fgmembersite->UserName()) {
      $fullname = $info['name'];
      $username = $info['username'];
      $password = $info['password'];
      $email = $info['email'];
      $url = $info ['url'];
      break;
    }
  }

  $answer = $_POST['answer'];
  if ($answer == "correct") {
    "UPDATE `simplelogin`.`member`
     SET `url` = 'ques1.php'
     WHERE
       `member`.`name` = '$fullname' 
       AND `member`.`email` = '$email'
       AND `member`.`username` = '$username' 
       AND `member`.`password` = '$password' 
       AND `member`.`confirmcode` = 'y'
       AND `member`.`url` = '$url'";

    //in place of above update query i had also used
    //"UPDATE  member 
    //SET url = 'ques1.php'
    //WHERE username = '$username'"

    Header("Location:ques1.php");

  } else {

    Header("Location: ques.php");

  }

?>
```

---

```
function UserName() {
  return isset($_SESSION['user_name'])?$_SESSION['user_name']:'';
}
```

---

login.php

```
<?php

  require_once("./include/membersite_config.php");

  if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

    if ($fgmembersite->Login()) {

      //$fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("login-home.php");

      mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 
      mysql_select_db("simplelogin") or die(mysql_error());  

      $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM member") or die(mysql_error()); 
      while ($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) {
        if ($info['username']==($fgmembersite->SafeDisplay('username'))) {
          $url = $info['url'];
          break;
        }
      }

      $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("$url");

    }
  }

?>
```

In `login.php` I am retrieving the URL from the database and redirecting the user - by default URLfor the user is ques.php.

Why is my query not updating the url in my database?

Comment: Try to make a very short example, not simply copying your whole code and get others to correct your mistakes.

Comment: while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))
    {
    //Print $info['username'] ;
    if($info['username']==$fgmembersite->UserName())
    {
    $username=$info['username'];
     break;
     }}
     $answer = $_POST['answer'];
     if ($answer == "correct")
     {
     sql_query("UPDATE  member SET url = 'ques1.php' WHERE username    = '$username'");
     }

Comment: created a short example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9599008/update-query-is-not-updating-url-in-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is you are looping a set of database results and comparing against a value that you already have, just to get the value that you already have. At best this verifies that the user exists in the database, at worst it does nothing at all.

Really you need to be using the Primary Key of your database table for the `UPDATE`. Best practice dictates that this should be an auto-incrementing integer, which has no relevance to the data other than to identify the row. When you initialise the `$fgmembersite` object this value should be stored in it, so it can easily be used in any database query which requires a reference to the user. At worst, a unique index should be present on the `username` column of the table.

You can can remove the `SELECT` query completely - you already have the username, so you can just use this directly in the `UPDATE`:

---

check.php:

```
<?php

  require_once("./include/membersite_config.php");

  // Redirect to login page if not already authenticated
  if (!$fgmembersite->CheckLogin()) {
    $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("login.php");
    exit;
  }

  // Define DB connection info in variables for readability/maintainability
  $dbHost = 'localhost';
  $dbUser = 'root'; // NEVER use root for a live website!
  $dbPass = ''; // A blank root password? Really?
  $dbName = 'simplelogin';

  // Connect to database - NEVER show the result of mysql_error() in a live site!
  mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass) or die(mysql_error()); 
  mysql_select_db($dbName) or die(mysql_error()); 

  if ($_POST['answer'] == 'correct')

    // Update the database with the new URL
    $query = "
      UPDATE `member`
      SET `url` = 'ques1.php'
      WHERE `username` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($fgmembersite->UserName())."'
    ";
    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    // This line should help you debug the query. REMOVE IT before putting this script on a live site!
    if (!mysql_affected_rows()) die("No rows were affected by the query.\nQuery: $query\nError: ".mysql_error());

    // Redirect to ques1.php
    // Note that a header redirect should provide a FULL url, not just a relative path.
    header("Location:ques1.php");

  } else {

    // Redirect to ques.php
    header("Location: ques.php");

  }

?>
```

---

login.php

```
<?php

  require_once("./include/membersite_config.php");

  if (isset($_POST['submitted']) && $fgmembersite->Login()) {

    // Define DB connection info in variables for readability/maintainability
    $dbHost = 'localhost';
    $dbUser = 'root'; // NEVER use root for a live website!
    $dbPass = ''; // A blank root password? Really?
    $dbName = 'simplelogin';

    // Connect to database - NEVER show the result of mysql_error() in a live site!
    mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass) or die(mysql_error()); 
    mysql_select_db($dbName) or die(mysql_error()); 

    // Fetch the URL from the database
    $query = "
      SELECT `url`
      FROM `member`
      WHERE `username` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($fgmembersite->UserName())."'
    ";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    if (!mysql_num_rows($result)) die('Invalid user name');
    $info = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $url = $info['url'];

    // Redirect to URL
    // Add some error checking to verify that $url actually contains something valid!
    $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL($url);

  } else {

    // What happens if the condition fails?

  }

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
"UPDATE `simplelogin`.`member` SET `url` = 'ques1.php' WHERE 
  `member`.`name`  ='$fullname' 
AND `member`.`email` = '$email' AND `member`.`username` = '$username' 
AND `member`.`password` = '$password' 
AND `member`.`confirmcode` = 'y' AND `member`.`url` = '$url'" ;
```

Doesnt appear to be running as a query, you haven't placed it within the `mysql_query()` function so it has no idea what you are trying to do with that statement.

Try this instead:

```
mysql_query(
"UPDATE `simplelogin`.`member` SET `url` = 'ques1.php' WHERE 
`member`.`name`  ='$fullname' 
AND `member`.`email` = '$email' AND `member`.`username` = '$username' 
AND `member`.`password` = '$password' 
AND `member`.`confirmcode` = 'y' AND `member`.`url` = '$url'");
```

**Updated due to comments below:**

Try this, it's been rewritten and simplified and should work, if not please port of you get the error message or not

```
mysql_query("
    UPDATE
        member
    SET
        url = 'ques1.php'
    WHERE
        name = '$fullname'
    AND
        email = '$email'
    AND
        username = '$username'
    AND
        password = '$password'
    AND
        confirmcode = 'y'
    AND
        url = '$url'
") or die('Unable to update members URL: ' . mysql_error());
```

Comment: check the inverted comma's (replace ` with ' ), may be that is creating problem

Comment: @user1253753 Updated my answer, also what exactly is `$url` passing? and are you sure that the query is meeting all the criteria? e.g. is it finding a record in the database which matches the name, email, username, password, confirmcode and url exactly?

Comment: it dint prompt any error ! and not updated the url...in the database...........   $url is passing the last visited url of the user....and url is the new page to which the user will be redirected if the answer is correct..  exactly it is doing the same thing that u understood.

Comment: @user1253753 Hmm, well all I can suggest is that it is unable to find a record matching all that criteria, first thing you should try is to echo out all of the variables: `$fullname` `$email` `$username` `$password` and  `$url` and make sure it is returning the expected results, then id suggest going in to something like phpmyadmin and querying your database to see if it returns any rows matching the values of the variables above.

Answer (score 1):

execute the query dude.... use `mysql_query("$your_update query");`