# Update query is not updating url in database

Tags: php, mysql

There is a page `ques.php`; if the user's answer is correct he will be directed to next `ques1.php`. The answer posted by the user is checked by `check.php` and I want to store this new url `ques1.php` in this user's account. I want to update his url to `ques1.php` in the database.

check.php

```
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))
{
    // Print $info['username'] ;
    if($info['username'] == $fgmembersite->UserName())
    {
        $username=$info['username'];
        break;
    }
}

$answer = $_POST['answer'];

if ($answer == "correct")
{
    sql_query("UPDATE  member SET url = 'ques1.php' WHERE username = '$username'");
}
```

In `login.php` I am retrieving the url directing it to the user. By default url for the user is `ques.php`. Why does my query not updating the url in my database? Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [why it is not updating url in database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598587/why-it-is-not-updating-url-in-database)

Comment: I would try writing the sql query to a variable and printing that to screen. Then when you have that try running it directly in MySQL. I'm sure you will see the problem then. My guess is `$username` is not being populated correctly.

Comment: That whole code could and should be summed up as: `if ($_POST['answer'] == 'correct') { mysql_query("UPDATE \`member\` SET \`url\` = 'ques1.php' WHERE \`username\` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($fgmembersite->UserName())."'") or die(mysql_error()); }`- when you have found the problem, you should remove the `or die()`

Comment: Sorry to ask but you are updating like `mysql_query("UPDATE  member SET url = 'ques1.php' WHERE username = '$username'");` right ?
Just wondering because you wrote up there `sql_query("UPDATE  member SET url = 'ques1.php' WHERE username = '$username'");`

Comment: @sachyn ya tht is written by mistake....i hav used mysql_query("");

Answer (score 0):

First try to print all values of variables, you caome to know where is the problem...

i think, you are making small mistake, above strategy will give you clear idea..

One more suggestions, if you are asking many questions to user and switching to various pages...then dont use post, create session when user login and destroy it when user log out..